# How to make equal space between words - python

Tags: python

(SORRY FOR BAD ENGLISH)
Im working at cmd.
I want to do that thing:

```
file_name              DIR
file_name_3            DIR
file_name_545          DIR
file_name_LlK          DIR
```

Instead of doing that thing:

```
file_name          DIR
file_name_3          DIR
file_name_545          DIR
file_name_LlK          DIR
```

I tryied to do this in loop:

```
print data.ljust((20 - len(data) + 20)) if len(data) <= 20 else (data[0:17] + '...').ljust(20)), 'DIR'
```

But that thing not working becase there are letters bigger then another, then 'ljust' the words makes it not possible.

Comment: Did not look at your code but if the problem is the letters being different sizes you need to use a monospace font in your terminal

Comment: How about `print data,(20-len(data))*' ','DIR'`?

Comment: @barak manos It worked! what did you do there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use format strings.

```
"{:20}{}".format(data,"DIR")
```

The same with `ljkust()`

```
data.ljust(20) + "DIR"
```

See `help(str.ljust)` to understand `ljust`

Comment: There is still the prolem of the actual width of the speciphic letters in the wanted data word.

Comment: This should be equivalent to @barak manos solution. I think you do not use a monospace font as jeff carey already mentioned.

Comment: I tryied now to do your answer too and its work. why does it dofferent from 'ljust'?

Answer (score 0):

First, find the widest point in your data.  I assume you have a list of tuples.

```
col_width = max(tup[0] for tup in list_of_tuples)
for tup in list_of_tuples:
    print(tup[0].ljust(col_width), tup[1].ljust(colwidth))
```

`ljust` is the function you want, but I think you are setting the columns on different lines to different widths, which is not what you want.